# How can I run the code with tensorflow which is installed on MAC?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running a code and I have MAC.I am trying to train an Artificial Neural Network. I thought to use keras.

I have written this code:

There is the following error:

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 13>()
11 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
12 from numpy import loadtxt
---> 13 import tensorflow as tf
14 from tensorflow import keras
16 start='2017-06-26'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

But I get the following, so tensoflow exists. What can I change? Do I have to change the version that is installed? Or do we have to put another library? Any hint will be appreciated....

pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 0.12.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: http://tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: numpy, protobuf, six, wheel

Do you have an idea?

Code:

````
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) 
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])```
````

Comment: You have multiple python versions installed and pip refers to only one of those versions (likely Python 2), else how would you have installed a 4-5 year old version of TensorFlow?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy So what can I do, so that I can use tensorflow? You mean that I have to delete some versions of Python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install latest stable Tensorflow version using following commands

```
python3 -m venv ~/tensorflow-metal
source ~/tensorflow-metal/bin/activate
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```